# AVFoundation framework taking around 250-300ms to deliver buffers to CaptureOutput. Its Adding latency while rendering

Tags: objective-c, macos, objective-c++, screen-capture

I am using AVFoundation framework to Grab Screen. 
I'm registered queue like this

```
*dispatch_sync (mainQueue, ^{
    BOOL ret;
    if (captureScreen)
      ret = [self openScreenInput];
    else
      ret = [self openDeviceInput];
    if (!ret)
      return;
    output = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
    [output setSampleBufferDelegate:self
                              queue:workerQueue];
    output.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = YES;
    output.videoSettings = nil; /* device native format */
    session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    [session addInput:input];
    [session addOutput:output];
    *successPtr = YES;
  });*
```

As Soon as it grab the buffers those will get delivered to workerQueue.
In CaptureOutput code -

```
*- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput
didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
       fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
    GstClockTime timestamp, duration;
  [bufQueueLock lock];
  if (stopRequest) {
    [bufQueueLock unlock];
    return;
 }
 if ([bufQueue count] == BUFFER_QUEUE_SIZE)
  {
    [bufQueue removeLastObject];
  }
  [bufQueue insertObject:(__bridge id)sampleBuffer
                 atIndex:0];
  [bufQueueLock unlockWithCondition:HAS_BUFFER_OR_STOP_REQUEST];
}*
```

But when render the delivered buffers I'm getting about 250-300ms delay.This is too just because of Grabber.
If anyone has solution please post it.
Thanks In advance

Comment: Buffers are not dropping I verified in function didOutputDropSampleBuffer